# scrapy speed up crawling

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am currently crawling a website to extract product information. The site consists of millions[around 20 millions] of product information and i need to extract each of those . I need to speed up the crawling speed as my crawler is currently scraping only few hundred pages per minute.

Here is my sample code of crawler.

```
class XYSspider(CrawlSpider):
name = "XYZ"

allowed_domains = ["www.xyz.info"]
start_urls = ['http://www.xyz.info/']

rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'\.kat$'), follow=True),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/id_\d+/'), callback='parse_product'),
]

def parse_product(self, response):
    item = DmozItem()
    item['title'] = response.xpath('//title/text()').extract()[0].encode('utf-8')
    yield item
```

Is there any way i can speed up the crawling process. At the current speed it would take me days to scrape all data. Any insights will be really helpful. Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have concurrent requests per domain set to 32 in settings.py.

If that does not help its most likely the site throttling you. Sites typically have some sort of not/spider/crawl detection and tend to either block or throttle if they detect lots of requests from the same IP.

I use http://www.crawlera.com which is run by the scrapy team.  It routes all of your requests through their proxy network and handles bans, etc. Its the only way I was able to scrape at high speeds.

Answer (score 0):

you can set concurrent request as much as you want and crawlera is useful when the site is blocking you because crawlera is kind of proxy rotator which pass different IPs with every request. and of course its paid so you have to spend money. So, before buying some extra service i will recommend to have a try with your crawl. you can -

1) try connecting your crawl to high speed internet as it matters to large extent.

2) try to split a single crawl to many and run the spider.

3) you can reduce download delay if possible.

any many.....